# Post to web page text box

Tags: c#

Ive searched all of google and i cant seem to find the method for doing this when it seems so simple! All i have is a text box on a  webpage, and given the text box id i want to write a value in it and press a button. So far i have:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://ps766677/TestWebApplication/Default.aspx");
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("455646:8980");
        request.Proxy = proxy;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        string postData = GetData();
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But the actual 'GetData' method is lost on me! 
Can anyone tell me what the GetData method should contain, im assuming returning a string of some sort of name value collection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postData` should contain the string of POST data that the server is expecting.  You can download [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966), and it will allow you to see what the server is expecting.  You take those variables(and values) and append them together with the `&`, and that will be your `postData` string.

An example would be:

The server is expecting `UserName` and `Password` to come as POST data.  Your string would look like...

```
  string postData = string.Format("UserName={0}&Password={1}", "someUserName", "somePassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Watin and Watin Test Recorder you could implement this automatically and then grab the C# outputted script as a reference